# Interpretation of Sum Sq in ANOVA with numeric independent variable

Tags: r, anova

I don't know how to interpret the Sum of Squares in a numeric independent variable.

```
summary(aov(Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length + Species, iris))
##               Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
## Petal.Length   1  80.26   80.26 2487.02  < 2e-16 ***
## Species        2   1.60    0.80   24.77 5.48e-10 ***
## Residuals    146   4.71    0.03                     
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

The sum of squares in Species are clear to me (sum of squared deviations from the group means) but how to interpret them if you have a numeric independent variable like Petal.Length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The components of this linear model are not orthogonal so we cannot 
calculate the sum of squares (SS) of each component independently of the others. Rather we must take a sequence of model comparisons. In this case `aov` 
considers these models owing to the order in which the components were listed in the formula.

```
fm0 <- lm(Petal.Width ~ 1, iris)                       # null model
fm1 <- lm(Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length, iris)
fm2 <- lm(Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length + Species, iris)  # full model
```

Note that the residual sum of squares (RSS) of a model `fm` is `sum(resid(fm)^2)` and R has a function specifically for this which is `deviance(fm)`.  Keeping this in mind we can decompose the RSS of the null model like this:

```
deviance(fm0)                     # RSS of null model
= (deviance(fm0) - deviance(fm1)  # SS of Petal.Length
+ (deviance(fm1) - deviance(fm2)  # SS of Species
+  deviance(fm2)                  # RSS of full model
```

and each sum of squares reported in the table in the question is one of the
lines above.  That is,

```
deviance(fm0) - deviance(fm1)   # SS of Petal.Length
## [1] 80.25984                 

deviance(fm1) - deviance(fm2)   # SS of Species
## [1] 1.598453

deviance(fm2)                   # RSS of full model
## [1] 4.711643
```

### Note

Note that the SS values we get depend on the sequence of models we use.  For example, if we use this sequence which considers `Species` before `Petal.Length` (whereas above we considered `Petal.Length` and then `Species`) we get difference SS values.

```
fm0  # same null model as above
fm1a <- lm(Petal.Width ~ Species, iris)
fm2 # same full model as above

deviance(fm0) - deviance(fm1a)   # SS of Species
## [1] 80.41333

deviance(fm1a) - deviance(fm2)   # SS of Petal.Length
## [1] 1.444957

deviance(fm2)                    # RSS of full model
## [1] 4.711643
```

and note that this does correspond to aov if we list the components in that order, i.e. this time we listed `Species` before `Petal.Length` to change the sequence of models that `aov` would consider:

```
summary(aov(Petal.Width ~ Species + Petal.Length, iris))
##               Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
## Species        2  80.41   40.21 1245.89  < 2e-16 ***
## Petal.Length   1   1.44    1.44   44.77 4.41e-10 ***
## Residuals    146   4.71    0.03                     
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```