# R: Calculating ANOVA Sum sqr for a model with interacting numerical and categorical variables

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm, anova

I need to know how it is calculated the Sum Sqr column of the anova() function in R, for a linear model with the form:

```
modelXg <-lm(Y ~ X * group, data)
```

(which is equivalent to `lm(Y~ X+group+X:group, data=dat)` )

where: "X" is a **numerical variable**, and "group" is a **categorical** one.

The function `anova(modelXg)` returns a table like:

```
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: TMIN
                  Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq  F value    Pr(>F)    
X                  1    6476  6476.1 282.9208 < 2.2e-16 ***
group              1    1176  1176.4  51.3956 7.666e-13 ***
X:group            1      64    64.2   2.8058   0.09393 .  
Residuals      45130 1033029    22.9                       
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

What I need is to know how to calculate all the terms of the **Sum Sq** column, described in a way as easy and reproducible as possible, because I need to implement it in C#.

I already searched a lot accross the Net, but I didn't find this exact case. I found some useful info in [Interpretation of Sum Sq in ANOVA with numeric independent variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58802911/interpretation-of-sum-sq-in-anova-with-numeric-independent-variable)  but it is incomplete for this case, because there the model does not involve the interaction between both variables.

Comment: Difference of predictions and outcomes squared and summed. To get predictions need model coefficients.

Comment: You can look directly at the implementation that @IRTFM describes by looking at the code in `stats::anova.lm`